# Sound interference on Macbook Pro when connected to network via ethernet

Tags: macbook-pro, network, audio, ethernet

I have discovered that when My Macbook Pro (Early 2011, Mountain Lion 10.8.5) has an active ethernet connection, there is audible audio static/interference via the headphone socket.

The ethernet connection comes via a router which in turn is connected to ethernet via powerline. The audio interference is not there when I connect to the network via WIFI.

I would rather have an ethernet connection so am wondering if there is anything I can do to prevent this interference?

Switching off the powerline adapter at the wall instantly stops the static / interference so I'm pretty sure it is related to that.

Comment: Starting from your MBP, there is an Ethernet cable going to a power adapter plugged into a wall socket. There is also a thin headphone cable going to your headphone.
Did I understood your local cabling correctly?
If yes, how far are these 2 cables from each other?

Comment: MBP -> ethernet cable -> router -> ethernet cable2 -> powerline adapter -> wallsocket. The cables are near to each other. It would not be practical to have that much distance between them due to the proximity of the headphone and ethernet ports.

Comment: Does only unplugging the Ethernet cable at the MBP socket suppress the interference?

Comment: Put this clearer description of your cabling in your original post.